# update state of component using jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

I am trying to update the state of my component in jest.

What I am trying to do is check that when the state value of `updated` is set to `true` then the new props should not change the value of the state.
From answers I have read on here I assumed I could do the following to update the state of a component.

```
Game.setState({
    updated: true
});
```

Here is my code below.

```
const props = {
  goals: "0"
};

it("should should not update the state of goals when the value prop is changed if updated value in state is set to true", () => {
    renderer.render(<Game {...props} />, div);

    Game.setState({
        updated: true
    });

    Game.componentWillReceiveProps({
        goals: "2"
    });

    expect(Game.state.goals).toBe("0");    
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can work with the instance

```
const gameRender = renderer.create(<Game {...props} />)
const gameInstance = gameRender.getInstance()

gameInstance.setState({ updated: true })
```

etc etc. your code references the constructor, not the instance.

Comment: Where do you import "renderer" ?